# rails4 accessing params in controller from fullcalendar (3rd party API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters, fullcalendar

I have a rails4 app and I'm trying to integrate it with fullcalendar. For fetching only the displayed events from db I'm trying to use `params['start']` and `params['end]` for my between_time scope. If I check the value of start and end params, the console says the value is nil. It's weird since in the logs I can see them for the json request. Why is it nil then? What should I do to be able to use them for my scope?

controller

```
@user = current_user
@event = Event.new
@events = Event.allevents(current_user).between_time(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render: @events }
end
```

logs on server

```
Started GET "/users/1/events" for ::1 at 2016-01-02 15:05:31 -0800
15:05:31 puma.1       | Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
15:05:31 puma.1       |   Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1"}

Started GET "/users/1/events?start=2015-12-27&end=2016-01-03&_=1451775933354" for ::1 at 2016-01-02 15:05:34 -0800
15:05:34 puma.1       | Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
15:05:34 puma.1       |   Parameters: {"start"=>"2015-12-27", "end"=>"2016-01-03", "_"=>"1451775933354", "user_id"=>"1"}
```

The following code is an example app I checked. In this code the params seem to be working properly. I don't see the difference compared to my code when it comes to getting the params.

```
def get_events
  start_time = Time.at(params[:start].to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
  end_time   = Time.at(params[:end].to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)

  @events = Event.where('
              (starttime >= :start_time and endtime <= :end_time) or
              (starttime >= :start_time and endtime > :end_time and starttime <= :end_time) or
              (starttime <= :start_time and endtime >= :start_time and endtime <= :end_time) or
              (starttime <= :start_time and endtime > :end_time)',
              start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time)
  events = []
  @events.each do |event|
    events << { id: event.id,
                title: event.title,
                description: event.description || '', 
                start: event.starttime.iso8601,
                end: event.endtime.iso8601,
                allDay: event.all_day,
                recurring: (event.event_series_id) ? true : false }
  end
  render json: events.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access them as symbols when they are actually strings

```
params[:start]
```

Need to replaced as

```
params["start"]
```

Comment: In my code it is string. The code with the symbols is the example from another app that works, but I tried both way.

Comment: Padamanaban, I would if it were right! The code works regardless I use ['start'] or [:start]. I don't wanna confuse the guys with marking it as right.

Comment: Ohh, sry I see what you are talking about! I just copied the code into the answer before I made it consistent. I could write-- if params['start'] && params[:end]  --and still would work

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I forgot that the params only get available later on when fullcalendar sends an AJAX request after html is loaded. My problem was the date/time formatting. The `Time.at(params['start'].to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)` was not working for me. I don't know why, maybe the fullcalendar API has changed. The current format that gets sent over is `Parameters: {"start"=>"2015-12-27".....`, so I changed the code to `params['start'].to_datetime.to_formatted_s(:db)` and now it's working.